# How to make a modification take affect without restarting nginx?

Tags: nginx

Apache has a `graceful` option which can scan for modification in `http.conf` without restarting Apache. What about nginx?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

nginx supports the following signals :

```
TERM, INT - Quick shutdown
QUIT - Graceful shutdown
HUP - Configuration reload: Start the new worker processes with a new configuration, Gracefully shutdown the old worker processes
USR1 - Reopen the log files
USR2 - Upgrade Executable on the fly
WINCH - Gracefully shutdown the worker processes
```

HUP is what you are looking for, so `sudo kill -HUP pid (nginx pid)`

source : 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html

Comment: I like the [answer below](https://serverfault.com/a/108750/561691) better.

Answer (score 146):

Use nginx -s reload

Comment: ^This 100%. Worked a charm.

Comment: This didn't take http basic authentication changes into effect for me.

Answer (score 23):

Usually nginx's init-script has `reload` action, i.e:

- Linux `/etc/init.d/nginx reload`
- FreeBSD `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/nginx reload`

Answer (score 2):

`service nginx reload` ?

P.S. Doesn't work on Windows.

Answer (score -2):

I wrote about how to restart nginx with zero downtime a while ago. This may be helpful for you.

http://tumblelog.jauderho.com/post/101514948/restart-nginx-with-zero-downtime

Comment: Your blog thing has no actual information.

Comment: `USR2` is for upgrading the executable, not for simple config reloading.